# How to use await in async using javascript javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have object like this:

```
module.exports = class WebWrapper {

    constructor() {
        //
    } 

    async init() {
        //some long code
        //open browser, go to some url
        console.log("A");
    }

    async close() {
        //some code
        //close browser
        console.log("B")
    }

};
```

In code, I am using instance like this:

```
var w = new webWrapper();
w.init();
w.close();
```

When I run the code, the output is:

```
B
A
```

Why? How can I use await to wait for `init` function close and then run `close` function?

Excepted output is:

```
A
B
```

Full example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

module.exports = class WebWrapper {

    constructor() {
        var browser;
        var page;
    } 

    async init() {
        this.browser = await puppeteer.launch(
        {
            headless: false
        });
        this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
        await this.page.setRequestInterceptionEnabled(true);

        await this.page.setViewport({
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080
        });

        await this.page.on('request', request => {
            request.continue(); // pass it through.
        });

        await this.page.on('response', response => {
            const req = response.request();
            console.log(req.method, response.status, req.url);
        });

        await this.page.goto('https://example.com');
        await this.page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
        console.log("A");
    }

    async close() {
        console.log("B");
        await this.browser.close();
    }

};
```

Comment: It does log `A B` for me. But you could write `w.init().then(w.close);`.

Comment: Sure, its only example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call close in a then()

```js
class WebWrapper {

    constructor() {
        //
    } 

    async init() {
        //some long code
        //open browser, go to some url
        console.log("A");
    }

    async close() {
        //some code
        //close browser
        console.log("B")
    }

};

var w = new WebWrapper();
w.init().then(() => {
    console.log('Some other code');
    w.close();
});
```

Comment: What about call like this: `w.init(); console.log("some other code"); w.close();`?

Comment: Its not working, see my edited post, I added full example.

Comment: B is being printed before A ?